# .htaccess rewriterule keep parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I currently have this line in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ /test/?type=post&year=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

It allows a URL like this:

```
/test/?type=post&year=2014&title=hello
```

to be accessed like this:

```
/test/2014/hello/
```

However, sometimes I have even another GET variable on the rewritten URL:

```
/test/2014/hello/?page=2
```

However, the get variable `page` isn't read by the PHP file on the page. So in other words, how can I alter my .htaccess file to allow the other get variables (added onto the rewritten URL) to be used and read by the PHP file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a QSA flag to your rewrite rule, so that the brackets look like this:

```
[L,QSA]
```

This tells apache to append any existing query string to the new query string in the target (mode=allBrands).

more Info there: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteFlags+QSA

Comment: Broken link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteFlags+QSA